# How to change Django admin panel login-form requirement

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to set up multiple Admin panels for different groups.
Like user from "Management" group can only login into Management-Panel
not to administration panel or any other..

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom `AuthenticationForm` subclass and overwrite `confirm_login_allowed()`
2. Create a custom `AdminSite` subclass and overwrite [`has_permission()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/admin/sites/#AdminSite.has_permission) and set  [`login_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.login_form) to your custom form class.